# Referencing Variables in Micronaut Caches

Tags: caching, microservices, micronaut

I was wondering how to include Path variables in the Micronaut caching annotation.

Example:

```java
@Get("/test/{name}")
public String getName(@PathVariable String name){
  return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Now imagine this would be some computationally expensive operation for a user. Obviously, I have to include the user name in the cache key to be able to retrieve or invalidate it. Sadly I havent found any docs on this, so maybe someone here has a clue.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to cache the controller endpoint itself (as opposed to a service it is delegating to), you could configure the cache in `application.yml`:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: yourapp
  caches:
    somecachename:
      expire-after-write: 30m
      maximum-size: 10
```

Then use that cache:

```java
import io.micronaut.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.PathVariable;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @Get("/test/{name}")
    @Cacheable("somecachename")
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name) {
        System.out.println("Here we are " + name);
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

You will need a dependency on whatever cache you are using, for example, to use caffeine:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-caffeine")
```

Comment: So the common practice would be to cache the methods that the controller endpoint is calling? 

And if yes, does the cache extension automatically look at the method arguments to determine the cache key or how does that work?

Comment: "So the common practice would be to cache the methods that the controller endpoint is calling?" - That is common practice, but that doesn't necessarily mean doing it another way is wrong. Knowing more about your app would be required to know. "And if yes, does the cache extension automatically look at the method arguments to determine the cache key or how does that work?" The cache extension does by default look at the method arguments, regardless of whether that is happening in controller or some other bean.

Comment: In my case, I have an endpoint to request user data and one to change it. 

For example

GET /user/{username}/info
POST /user/{username}/info

Now the GET should get cached but invalidated when the data is changed for example by calling the POST endpoint

Comment: I wouldn't say this is definitely the right approach without knowing more but it might be the case that a good option for you is to have a service bean that has a `@Cacheable` annotation on the helper method(s) that support the `GET` and a `@CacheInvalidate` method that is invoked on the `POST`.

Comment: But even when annotating the helper methods, I only want the data for that one updated user to be invalidated. Is that done automatically if I name the passed variables the same or how does that work?

Comment: "Is that done automatically if I name the passed variables the same or how does that work?" - By default, yes, the passed variables are used in cache key generation.

Comment: You can also use `@CachePut` to cause values to be pushed into the cache which differs from `@Cacheable` in that a `@CachePut` will be run and have its return value added to the cache, which is what `@Cacheable` does, except a `@CachePut` method will always run when invoked, regardless of whether an entry already exists in the cache for the related key.  A `@Cacheable` method might not run when invoked because the value could already be in the cache (that is the whole point of the annotation).  I hope that helps.